# How could I get object from another class

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview

If I want get one Label.text from View1,
so I set in  firstView.h

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
 NSMutableArray *menuList;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *menuList;

@end
```

---

in secondView.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource> {

 UILabel *comboView;

}
@property (nonatomic,retain)UILabel *comboView;
@end
```

---

in secondView.m

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
[firstViewController.menuList addObject:comboView.text];
```

---

but when I want to get object from menuList in firstView(self.menuList)
It become "null"!!!

What's the problem??
Thanks

Mini

Comment: Mark your code as Sample code if you want some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided is very limited, did you remember to initialize the 'menuList' before adding objects? Objective C lets you add objects to uninitialized array's, so a mistake is easily made.